# Browser Tab Icon for Local System Icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, browser

*Am trying to do Browser Tab icon for the local System, it is not working but using HTTP static icon it works, Please help me to understand the problem with me.*

**PAGE 1 : This is not working**

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="C:/Documents and Settings/joseph.m/Desktop/firefox.ico">
```

**PAGE 1 : This is working**

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="file:///C:/Documents and Settings/joseph.m/Desktop/favicon.ico"/>
```

*Not tested, I'm on Linux*

Answer (score 0):

well,here's mine.this is working.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="C://Documents and Settings/joseph.m/Desktop/firefox.ico" />
```